# JNLP files will not launch from IE's temporary internet files folder

Tags: windows-7, java

Windows 7 machine. Have several different Java applications which launch from JNLP files on websites. The JNLP files download to 'Temporary Internet Files' and then do nothing from there. I cannot double-click to launch either but I can if I move them to another folder.

I have reinstalled Java and confirmed that the 'Enable Java Content in the browser' option is checked.

Comment: Which Java version do you have installed ? What is Java Security set to ?

Comment: Java 7 update 40 and the security settings are set to Medium. Keep in mind that moving the JNLPs to another folder (like Desktop) and double-clicking them launches the Java apps without issue, so I don't believe that its a version comptability problem.

Comment: Looks like a java security issue to me. Could you set the security to low and try.

Comment: No luck. Moved the settings for Java as low as I could. Also changed the JNLP/MIME associations option in the java control to always allow. I added the websites to Local Intranet in IE and changed the security on that zone to as low as it could go, still doesn't work. I also tried resetting IE.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem. it seems that java web start could not carry out the "browsing" task when discovering the size of Temporary Internet files (default 1,000MB). I tried reducing its size, it still works intermittently. However, if I invoke user' temporary Internet files (using windows explorer), it seems to work. looks like java web start doesn't have the stamina to browse and validate the size of Temp Internet files folder.
My solution was to add a small script to open user's Temp Internet Files folder to logon script in Apsense (or you can add to GPMC logon script).

it is an expensive workaround though...